# how can i test angular acrivated route subscribe together with snapshot data?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have code that i subscribe to activatedRoute.url and inside the subscription im accsessing the sanpshot data.
I created mock for the activatedRoute but my test keeps failing .

This is the test code

[This is the code i want to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7dWd.jpg)

[This is the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLO9M.jpg)

I have tried to to change the code without the subscription and it worked.
But when i try to do it inside the subscripion the test fails.

Comment: Please prefer copy/paste the code instead of showing as picture

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your test inside a `fakeAsync` with a `tick()` call to wait for the code inside the subscription.

```
it('should wait', fakeAsync(() => {
  ...
  component.ngAfterViewInit();
  tick();
  expect(something);
}));
```

Comment: Its not working also 

Comment: Can you please share the new test to help you? (as code, not as image). If you can share a little code-sandbox or a repo will be better!

Comment: I will do it . Thanks